# Is this the correct iterative version of the multiplicative update rule for matrix factorization?

Tags: matrix-decomposition

So we have $A_{m\times n}\approx P_{m\times k}Q_{k\times n}.$ Using the multiplicative update rule due to Lee we, in general, write that:
$$P\leftarrow  P \circ \frac{AQ^T}{PQQ^T}$$
and 
$$Q\leftarrow  Q \circ \frac{P^TA}{P^TPQ}.$$
Since I am working with very large matrices, I don't have access to the whole matrix in memory. Give $(i,j,A[i][j])$, I can fetch $P[i][:]$ and $Q[:][j],$ where $P[i][:]$ is the $i'$th row vector of the matrix $P$ and $Q[:][j]$ is the $j$'th column vector of the matrix $Q.$ I therefore intend to write a method which does the following:

```
def update(i, j, matrix_value_at_ij):
    // Goal is to update the vector P[i][:] and Q[:][j]
    p_vect = get_vector_from_memory(i) // returns P[i][:] as a column vector
    q_vect = get_vector_from_memory(j) // return Q[:][j] as a column vector

    for c in range(k):
            p_vect[k] = p_vect[k]* (coeff_AQ_t)/(coeff_PQQ_t)
            q_vect[k] = q_vect[k]* (coeff_P_tA)/(coeff_P_tPQ)
```

I don't know how to compute `(coeff_AQ_t)/(coeff_PQQ_t)` and `(coeff_P_tA)/(coeff_P_tPQ)` under this constraint. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to instead peruse existing packages and frameworks that support the kind of large multiplications you need, as surely this is a widespread use case. For example TensorFlow should be able to do such updates as it has built-in logic for lazy-loading of weights. Even if your code is correct, it will likely be orders of magnitude slower than existing implementations of such multiplications.

Comment: @AlexR. You are right. But I intend to implement this algorithm from scratch.